# emacs における site-lisp とは

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacs の設定方法や、設定ファイルについて調べると、3rd パーティの elisp パッケージは、 (~/.emacs.d の中の) site-lisp に配置していく、みたいな記述をしばしば見かけます。

質問:

- site-lisp という単語とは、何を表しますか？
- site-lisp は、「3rd パーティパッケージの置き場」として、慣習的に利用されてきたディレクトリ名、と理解していますが、正しいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

文字通り site の lisp つまり「現地で作った lisp 」「現地で使う lisp 」でしょう。
[emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs) ユーザが作った lisp ファイル置き場でいいと思うです。
この「ユーザ」にはオイラ等直接 [emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs) を使うユーザも含まれますし、
いわゆる 3rd party ユーザも含んでよいと思います。
[emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs) の提供者以外の全て、のことでしょう。